# Using DateTime to find the amount of months (inclusive) between two dates

Tags: c#, datetime

I have two `DateTimes`, date1 and date2.

How do I get the difference in months?

2011/01/31 - 2011/02/01 should return 2.
2011/02/01 - 2011/02/01 should return 1.
2011/02/01 - 2012/03/01 should return 14.
etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
date2.Month - date1.Month + 1 + (date2.Year - date1.Year) * 12
```

Comment: Oh, I see my answer is the same as yours, so +1 for you because you were first.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
var diff = 12 * (d2.Year - d1.Year) + (d2.Month - d1.Month) + 1;
```